# How to get branch name of commit with Libgit2sharp?

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

I have a commit information, and I want to know branch name of this commit object. please help T.T

Comment: Git commits aren't necessarily on a branch. Some commits (especially older commits) can be found in the history of many branches. Some commits might not be on any branches (the branch may have been deleted, or rebased, or perhaps it was never on a branch at all). What you can do: you can look through all branches, and see whether your commit is an ancestor of the branch-commit.

Answer (score 0):

It might not give you the correct answer but `git log` has a --graph option (see https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History) that you can use to visualize the branch and the merge - so if you retrieve your particular commit you can follow on the branch and the merge.

for example:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" --graph
```